# JsonPath JUnit escape character for dots

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, junit

I have a json field which is called template.welcome.email and I am writing a unit test that checks if that field is present in the reply from the server but I can't find an escape for the dots in the name of the field.
The code of my test is :

```
@Test
public void testEmailTemplates() throws Exception {     
    mockMvc.perform(get("/emailTemplates")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .locale(Locale.UK)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))

        .andDo(print())
        .andExpect(status().isOk())

        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.template.welcome.email").exists())

        .andExpect(redirectedUrl(null))
        .andExpect(forwardedUrl(null));
}
```

But I get the following exception, because the dots are interpreted like paths:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: No value for JSON path: $.template.welcome.email, exception: invalid path
at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.evaluateJsonPath(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.exists(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:121)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.JsonPathResultMatchers$3.match(JsonPathResultMatchers.java:77)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:141)
at
```

Do you know any escape character for the jsonPath?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As [Ida](https://stackoverflow.com/users/636398/ida) [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22245630/2231972):

> Use brackets and quotes around your field. For example, if your field is valid.key.with.dot
>
> Refer to it as ['valid.key.with.dot'] and in JsonPath, try
>
> `JsonPath.read(jsonString, "$.['valid.key.with.dot']")`

Comment: Ohhh, that's why my path (with an escaped forward slash) isn't working!

Comment: Yes it is possible, see Ida's answer

Comment: I've updated the accepted answer. I would remove it altogether when/if OP accept the correct answer.

Comment: And how to do it in groovy?

Comment: Cool idea but when trying against SQL queries with Amazon Athena (prestodb)  fails since `"` not allowed heh  https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/functions/json.html ,

Answer (score 55):

Use brackets and quotes around your field. For example, if your field is *valid.key.with.dot*

Refer to it as `['valid.key.with.dot']` and in JsonPath, try

```
JsonPath.read(jsonString, "$.['valid.key.with.dot']")
```

See this thread also: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jsonpath/7YvgXWP1_7Y

Comment: This one works as well in other libraries that use JsonPath internally (for example REST-assured). Thanks Ida!

Comment: Just done this in SOAP UI too - JsonPath Match. Works perfectly!

Answer (score 5):

These days (e.g. `io.rest-assured.json-path:3.0.1`) the notation seems to be without brackets:

```
// Some Groovy OData V4 $count test
// Response looks like:
// { "@odata.count": 2, ... }
body "'@odata.count'", equalTo(2)
```

I found the corresponding hint [in this Git issue](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/326).