# camel-jsonpath to filter classname with path

Tags: json, apache-camel, jsonpath

My route to filter the json classname with class is

```
        <route>
            <from uri="file:D:/inputFolder/jsonpath"/>
            <choice>
              <when>
                <jsonpath>$..com.mycompany.app10.Person</jsonpath>
                <to uri="file:D:/inputFolder/jsonpath/output"/>
              </when>
            </choice>
        </route>
```

My sample input is

```
{"com.mycompany.app10.Person":{"firstName":"Gregory","surname":"Smith","type":"FAMILY"}}
```

In my route , if i use "$..Person" in the json path and my input is

{"Person":{"firstName":"Gregory","surname":"Smith","type":"FAMILY"}}

It is working fine!!

But classname with path is not working , is there any workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

The dot is an operator in JSONPath expressions. If you want to match an element with dots in its name, like `com.mycompany.app10.Person`, then you need to escape the dot in the expression.

`$..Person` won't ever match `com.mycompany.app10.Person`. The element to match is the fully qualified class name. The dots are part of the element name and have nothing to do with the structure of the JSON document.

If you want to match the class name you need to change the JSONPath expression to `$..['com.my.company.app10.Person']`. Or `$['com.my.company.app10.Person']` as the class name is the root.

Also see this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726859/jsonpath-junit-escape-character-for-dots) about escaping operator characters in JSONPath expressions.

Comment: if i use suggested JSONPath expression like <jsonpath>$..['com.my.company.app10.Person']</jsonpath> or <jsonpath  suppressExceptions="true">$['com.my.company.app10.Person']</jsonpath> both are not working

Comment: Maybe it is the implementation of Camel? I verified that it works here: [https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/](https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/)

Comment: i checked with my input {"com.mycompany.app10.Person":{"firstName":"Gregory","surname":"Smith","type":"FAMILY"}} it not working. what is the input you have tried.

Comment: I tried the JSON you provided in your question and it worked.