# JSON.net : get path of a JToken when nodes have dot?

Tags: json.net, jsonpath

There's a property Path on JToken. 
But it escapes the name of object with "[' ']" if the object name contains a "."

- XPATH : `dir/nested_dir/file.txt`
- JSON: `dir.nested_dir.['file.txt']`

Is there some other property that will return the path as an array of string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a built-in property that does this, but you can make an extension method that does what you want easily enough:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static string[] PathAsArray (this JToken token)
    {
        return token.AncestorsAndSelf()
                    .OfType<JProperty>()
                    .Select(p => p.Name)
                    .Reverse()
                    .ToArray();
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
var pathArray = token.PathAsArray();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("/", pathArray));
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GOdo7t

Note: the above extension method ignores any `JArrays` that might be in the path.  You will need to make adjustments to the code if you need to handle arrays.

Comment: Didn't know of dotnetfiddle. Quite cool. Thanks for that and your nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19727164/1555435

Use brackets and quotes around your field. For example, if your field is `valid.key.with.dot`

Refer to it as `['valid.key.with.dot']` and in JsonPath, try

```
JsonPath.read(jsonString, "$.['valid.key.with.dot']")
```

Check out this [dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/v7mOo0)